# Coinbase Pro API {"message":"invalid signature"}

Tags: php, laravel, coinbase-api

I'm running the thing through a Laravel project. I've been tearing my hair out for a while now. What I have so far is cribbed from the Coinbase Pro API documentation.

```
    $request_path = "/orders";
    $body = array('size' => $size, 'price' => $eth_price, 'side' => 'sell', 'product_id' => 'ETH-GBP' );
    $body = is_array($body) ? json_encode($body) : $body;

    $secret = my secret;

    $ch = curl_init("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/time");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'CoinbaseProAPI');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
      curl_close($ch);
      $timestamp = $result->epoch;
      $timestamp_rounded = intval(ceil($timestamp));

    $what = $timestamp_rounded.'POST'.$request_path.$body;
    $sig =  base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $what, base64_decode($secret), true));


    $ch = curl_init("https://api.pro.coinbase.com".$request_path) ;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true) ;
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'CoinbaseProAPI');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'CB-ACCESS-KEY: public_key',
        'CB-ACCESS-SIGN: '.$sig,
        'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE: passphrase',
        'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: '.$timestamp));
        $coinbasepro_response = curl_exec($ch) ;
        curl_close($ch) ;

    dd($coinbasepro_response);
```

The response I'm getting is an invalid signature. I'm stumped, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The response you are getting back would suggest that Coinbase is rejecting your API call. As such, you'd really need to query this with Coinbase as to what part of your call is incorrect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after much fiddling, I found out that I was missing a content-type header so I added:

```
"Content-Type: application/json"
```

to the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER array. I hope this helps someone!